# Ionic 2 dev and prod environment variables

Tags: android, angular, environment-variables, ionic2

I am working on Ionic 2 project and I want to configure it for a different environment like **Development** and **Production**. But, I have no idea where to put config files in ionic 2. Are there any ways to put config file and run commands

like

> ```
> ionic build android --prod
> ```

and

> ```
> ionic build android --dev
> ```

Answer (score 4):

There seems to be a ticket for that already:

https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues/1205

Comment: One commentor in that issue made a nice little package to help with it https://github.com/geeklearningio/gl-ionic2-env-configuration

Answer (score 0):

I used [ionic-configuration-service](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic-configuration-service) and it worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Webpack plugin can be used [webpack-environment-suffix-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-environment-suffix-plugin) to setup several environments for ionic.

**Install plugin**

`npm install webpack-environment-suffix-plugin --save`

**Create your own `webpack.config.js` file.**

```
const webpackConfig = require('@ionic/app-scripts/config/webpack.config');
const EnvironmentSuffixPlugin = require('webpack-environment-suffix-plugin');

const ionicEnv = ['prod', 'dev'];

const addPluginToWebpackConfig = (config, env) => {
  const plugins = config[env].plugins || [];

  config[env].plugins = [
    ...plugins,
    new EnvironmentSuffixPlugin({
      ext: 'ts',
      suffix: process.env.NODE_ENV || 'dev'
    })
  ];

  return config;
};

module.exports = () => ionicEnv.reduce(addPluginToWebpackConfig, webpackConfig);
```

**Update package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    //...
    "build": "<you build script>",
    "build:prod": "NODE_ENV=\"prod\" npm run build",
    "build:dev": "NODE_ENV=\"dev\" npm run build",
    "build:test": "NODE_ENV=\"qa\" npm run build
    //...
},
"config": {
   // path to a new webpack config file.
   "ionic_webpack": "./webpack.config.js" 
}
```